# Am I thinking about OAuth 2 correctly

Tags: oauth-2.0

I've been building and tinkering with Bearer tokens and OAuth/OAuth2 for a couple years now. And I feel like I have it decently understood, but when I search for how to do what I want, I can't seem to find it.

General understanding. There's a server that GRANTS tokens (and validates/invalidates/refreshes tokens as well). And then there's servers (or apps) that utilize the token. I'm not doing anything with external api libraries, but we have several company sites and I want to create a single login server that grants access tokens.

So I would have 1 server to GRANT the tokens, and then a separate API server that uses that token to authorize a user to endpoints and of course the front end portion. But the issue I seem to run into is figuring out how to setup a server to USE the token. Everyone just seems to explain how to create the server that grants it. That's cool, and I know how to get a token from google and use it. But I want to create a server that is granting authorization via access tokens.

So, my SPA app, lets say react, request an access token from server A which is an OAuth2 server. We're using credentials flow since it's company/registered users logging in. If they are successful, they are granted an access and identity token. Cool. Store those on the front end. Then, I want to request my...appointments from server B, the websites API server. I pass said access token as a bearer token. Server B should be setup as an OAuth 2 server but only as a client server. If the scope and client of the access token (and the secret of course) don't match the access token, the user is denied access to server B's endpoints.  Server B doesn't NEED to validate the access token since it's aware of the secret used from Server A. It can validate it itself.

Is this correct or am I massively looking at OAuth2 wrong?